# Which PHP script is overloading my VPS?

Tags: linux, php, vps, top

Is there a way to get the PHP script filename that is currently hammering my VPS?

For example, when I view "top", I see:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
7622 itil      17   0 61388  11m 6004 R 45.8  2.3   0:00.13 php
7626 itil      17   0 58360 8632 5440 R 24.6  1.6   0:00.07 php
```

How can I find out what file is being processed by PHP at that particular time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show the arguments passed to the comand, use the next command:

```
ps v -C php
```

If you just see something like `php somefile.php`, get the current working directory using:

```
readlink /proc/$PID/cwd
```

replace `$PID` by the PID of the process as shown by `ps`.

Comment: Thanks, ps does the job.  Is there a way to get the arguments in top?

Comment: Press the "c" key while top is running.